# Cleaning Data in CSV file for ML Model

Tags: machine-learning, data-cleaning

I'm trying to clean my data in jupyterlab by watching several tutorials, but I keep getting one or the other error every time. So I thought I'd come on stack overflow and ask if someone can help me.

This is the csv file I want to clean: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvOXB8kb-IHBgjaveis044GVoPpk

I'm building a machine learning model so I want to convert all the object values, but I don't know how to.

EDIT: I tried cleaning the data from scratch.

My code input:

```py
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
    criminal_data = pd.read_csv('database2.csv')
    X = criminal_data.drop(columns=['Agency Type', 'City', 'State', 
    'Crime Solved'])
    y = criminal_data['City']
    model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
    model.fit(X, y)
    criminal_data
```

The error message:

```py
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call 
    last)
    <ipython-input-117-4b6968f9994f> in <module>
          6 y = criminal_data['City']
          7 model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
    ----> 8 model.fit(X, y)
          9 criminal_data

    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
        896         """
        897 
    --> 898         super().fit(
        899             X, y,
    900             sample_weight=sample_weight,

    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
        154             check_X_params = dict(dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csc")
        155             check_y_params = dict(ensure_2d=False, dtype=None)
    --> 156             X, y = self._validate_data(X, y,
        157                                        validate_separately=(check_X_params,
        158                                                             check_y_params))

    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
        428                 # :(
        429                 check_X_params, check_y_params = 
    validate_separately
    --> 430                 X = check_array(X, **check_X_params)
        431                 y = check_array(y, **check_y_params)
        432             else:

    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
         61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
         62             if extra_args <= 0:
    ---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
         64 
         65             # extra_args > 0

    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in 
    check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, 
    copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
        614                     array = array.astype(dtype, casting="unsafe", 
    copy=False)
        615                 else:
    --> 616                     array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
        617             except ComplexWarning as complex_warning:
        618                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order, like)
        100         return _asarray_with_like(a, dtype=dtype, order=order, 
    like=like)
        101 
    --> 102     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
        103 
        104 

    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __array__(self, dtype)
       1897 
       1898     def __array__(self, dtype=None) -> np.ndarray:
    -> 1899         return np.asarray(self._values, dtype=dtype)
       1900 
       1901     def __array_wrap__(

    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, 
    order, like)
        100         return _asarray_with_like(a, dtype=dtype, order=order, 
    like=like)
        101 
    --> 102     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
        103 
        104 

    ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Anchorage'
```

​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to train your model with some data that is not numerical. Before using the model, you need to do encoding. You can try [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) for that.

```py
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
for column_name in X.columns:
    if X[column_name].dtype == object:
         X[column_name] = le.fit_transform(X[column_name])
    else:
         pass
```

If you have a combination of different data types in a row. Try below:

```py
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
for column_name in X.columns:
    X[column_name] = X[column_name].replace(np.nan, 'none', regex=True)
    X[column_name] = le.fit_transform(X[column_name].astype(str))
```

Comment: Getting new error: Encoders require their input to be uniformly strings or numbers. Got ['int', 'str']. The column which I'm trying to convert has no numerical data, just strings.

Comment: It seems to be in one (or more) of the columns, you have a mixture of different data types. It's really weird though. Can you check your dataframe and observe which one that is?

Comment: Hi, now the old error 'Could not convert String to float: 'January' is showing again.

Comment: ```X[column_name].astype(str)``` should convert everything in your dataset to ```str```. Can you give me the link of the data file or something? The link you gave in your question doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Hi Muhteva, thanks so much for helping me! My error of the string conversion has been resolved, however, I am getting a memory error which says 'Unable to allocate 1.06 GiB for an array with shape (638452, 1782) and data type uint8.' I am willing to shorten the data by removing a few rows, would that help in resolving the error?

Comment: If that size is correct, your data includes 638452 observations and 1782 fields. Actually number of observations can be ok but how does it include 1782 fields? Because it means that each of the observation is separated into 1782 different properties, which seems extraordinarily a lot. Try reducing the number of columns by selecting which fields are important for you and which are not. I believe it'll solve the problem.

Comment: so, deleting the columns, not rows, right?

Comment: Yep. Just keep the columns (fields) that will be useful for you.